# Variational discretization: proof that $u(x_i)=u_h(x_i)$

Tags: inequality, variational-analysis

Suppose $f \in L^2(0,1)$ and  $u \in H^1_0$ is the solution to the following problem:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 u'(x)v'(x) dx=\int_0^1 f(x)v(x)dx ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
\end{equation}
for all $v \in H^1_0(0,1)$.
I would now like to investigate the connection between the solution $u$ from above and the solution $u_h$ of the discrete problem
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1u_h'(x)v_h'(x) dx=\int_0^1f(x)v_h(x)dx ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)
\end{equation}
where now $u_h, v_h \in V_h:=\{v_h \in C(\bar{\Omega})|v_h(0)=v_h(1)=0 ~\text{and} ~ \text{for all} ~ j=1,..N: v_h|_{[x_i,x_i+1]}~ \text{is linear}\}$. 
$\Omega$ is the uniform grid $]0,1[$ with the grid points $x_i=ih$ for all $i=0,..,N$.

I have the feeling that for the solutions $u_h$ and $u$ from the second and first problem respectively it should hold that:
\begin{equation}
u(x_i)=u_h(x_i)
\end{equation}
for all grid points $x_i$ in our mesh. Therefore, I tried to prove this assumption:

By using partial integration I get that
\begin{equation}
\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} u_h'(x)v_h'(x) dx= u_h(x_{i+1})v'(x_{i+1})-u_h(x_i)v_h'(x_i)-\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}u_h''(xi)v_h(x_i)dx
\end{equation}
Since $u_h \in V_h$, i.e. $u_h$ is linear in the interval $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ the last term vanishes.

Now instead of $u_h$ let's consider $u_I$ which denotes the linear interpolant of the solution $u$, i.e. $u_I(x_i)=u(x_i)$ for all grid points $x_i$. Hence, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} u_I'(x)v_h'(x) dx= u_I(x_{i+1})v'(x_{i+1})-u_I(x_i)v_h'(x_i)
\end{equation}
I now wonder if there is a way to conclude that
\begin{equation}
u_h(x_{i+1})v'(x_{i+1})-u_h(x_i)v_h'(x_i)=u_I(x_{i+1})v'(x_{i+1})-u_I(x_i)v_h'(x_i)=u(x_{i+1})v'(x_{i+1})-u(x_i)v_h'(x_i).
\end{equation}
which would be equivalent to
\begin{equation}
v'(x_{i+1})[u_h(x_{i+1})-u(x_{i+1})]-v'(x_i)[u_h(x_i)-u(x_i)=0
\end{equation}
And therefore $u_h(x_i)=u(x_i)$ (is this conclusion correct?).

I know that I have not used the fact that (2) holds. But can I conclude from (2) also that
\begin{equation}
\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}u_h'(x)v_h'(x) dx=\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}f(x)v_h(x)dx?
\end{equation}
I am confused how to finish my proof. Am I on the right path?

Comment: I do not think that $u(x_i)=u_h(x_i)$. in general, you would expect $u_h(x_i)=u(x_i)+O(h^2)$ where $h$ is the maximum of $x_{i+1}-x_i$.

The mistake that I can see is that you are using the derivative of $v$ at the endpoints of the element. However, $v'(x_i)$ is not well defined since $v'$ is discontinuous at $x_i$.

Comment: Ok thank you! I have looked in my lecture notes again and they say that for the discertization of (1) with the space $V_h$ it holds that $u_h(x_i) =u(x_i). $ So is that wrong? Or is (2) not the discretization of (1)?

Comment: It could be a typo. $u_h(x_i)$ is an approximation of $u(x_i)$ but they are not necessarily equal. You can try a simple example with two elements and see what happens.

Comment: I'm struggling to find a counterexample. Could you help me finding one?

Comment: Consider the case $n=2$ and $f(x)=\sin(n \pi x)$, then $V_h$ is a one-dimensional space, it only contains multiples of the hat function $q$, where $q(0)=0$, $q(1/2)=1$ and $q(1)=0$. Now, the discrete variation problem is find $u_h=c q$ such that $(1)$ holds. You can do this by hand, If I am not mistaken, you should find $c=12/\pi^2$. In this case, $u_h(1/2)\ne u(1/2)$.